# Can you write an interface that requires a no-arg constructor or factory in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, factory-pattern

In Java, is there a way to enforce a constraint that any Class that implements an interface has a no-arg constructor?  If not can you enforce that it has a factory that returns an instance of the class?

Comment: Depending on why you want this, it is likely you can find a way to lift this requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not on the interface, but you can write a class with a factory method:

```
public abstract class Foo {

    private Foo() {}

    public static Bar createBar() {
        return new BarImpl();
    }

}

public interface Bar {}

Bar myBar = Foo.createBar();
```

That's how Java exposes their factory methods on classes like Calendar.java.

Answer (score 2):

> In Java, is there a way to enforce a constraint that any Class that implements an interface has a no-arg constructor?

Not at compile-time, no.

> If not can you enforce that it has a factory that returns an instance of the class?

Not at compile-time, no.

Unit tests can check for both of these, of course, if you can work out the types to check.

Answer (score 1):

No, to both. In general, though, you should neither want or need to do that.

Comment: How can you say there is never a case when I'd want to guarantee a certain behavior from a class.  If that is the case, why even have inheritance?

Comment: Joe, it's exactly because you want certain _behavior_ that you shouldn't mandate restrictions on _type_. A Java interface specifies exactly that - an interface. You generally shouldn't care what the run-time type of an object is; you just want to know what operations it supports (what interfaces it implements).

Comment: Actually, a number of popular frameworks would be well served by an interface that guarantees a no-arg constructor.  Frameworks like Hibernate, Stripes, and others will sometimes presume that a class has a no-arg constructor and will throw an error if it doesn't.

Comment: I think these are the exceptions rather than the rule.